# Why is this testing in React not working?

Tags: reactjs, testing

I wanted to test that a count increases whenever I clicked on a button, but it seems not to work. Please Help! Here is the code...

```
describe('checkbtn', () => {
    it('onClick', () => {
        const { queryByTitle } = render(<Counter />);
        const { queryByTitle } = render(<Counter />);
        const btn = queryByTitle('button1');
        const count = queryByTitle('count');
        expect(count.innerHTML).toBe(count.innerHTML);
        fireEvent.click(btn);
        expect(count.innerHTML).toBe(count.innerHTML + 1);
    })
})
```

Comment: Have you tried awaiting you `fireEvent`?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you expect some state to equal the same state + 1 here:

```
expect(count.innerHTML).toBe(count.innerHTML + 1);
```

It's the same as to write

```
const x = 2;
expect(x).toBe(x+2)
```

Second is that you try to add number to string which will result in not what you expect.

What you should do is to write explicit values in your test:

```
describe('checkbtn', () => {
    it('onClick', () => {
        const { queryByTitle } = render(<Counter />);
        const btn = queryByTitle('button1');
        const count = queryByTitle('count');
        expect(count.innerHTML).toBe('1');
        fireEvent.click(btn);
        expect(count.innerHTML).toBe('2');
    })
})
```